# codeigniter form with image upload

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, upload

I have a field of my form (which is uploading personal picture). So the user selects image from pc and submit the form.

Controller:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '100000';
    $config['max_width']     = '10240';
    $config['max_height']    = '7680';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($this->upload->data());
        $datafoto = $this->upload->data();
        $nm_file = time().$datafoto['orig_name'];
        $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
        $this->mkegiatan->update_foto($nm_file);
        copy('images/'.$datafoto['orig_name'], 'images/'.$nm_file);
    }
}
```

And contoller edit event like this:

```
  function edit_kegiatan()
        {

            $id_kegiatan = $this->uri->segment(4);

            //set validation properties

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal_kegiatan', 'Tanggal', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kegiatan', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');


            //run validation
            // jika dia ingin update data atau form validation error
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $data  = $this->mkegiatan->get_by_id($id_kegiatan);
                $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
                $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000';
                $config['max_width']  = '10240';
                $config['max_height']  = '7680';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))       //you forgot this
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    //print_r($this->upload->data());
                    $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
                    $nm_file = time().$datafoto['orig_name'];
                   $data = array(
                        'tanggal_kegiatan' => $this->input->post('tanggal_kegiatan'),
                        'nama_kegiatan' => $this->input->post('nama_kegiatan'),
                        'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
                        'image' => $nm_file
                );
                $this->mkegiatan->update_kegiatan($id_kegiatan,$data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil diupdate'));
                redirect(site_url('admin/kegiatan'));
                }
            }

            $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));



            //var_dump($data);
            //$tmp_data = array('id_kegiatan' => $id_kegiatan);

            $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/kegiatan/edit_kegiatan', $this->data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open(current_url(),'name=form'); ?>
                        <div class="fours fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="ui vertical segment">
                                    <div class="date field">
                                        <label>Tanggal</label>
                                        <div class="ui small icon input left">
                                            <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="xxxx-xx-xx" name="tanggal_kegiatan" value="<?php echo $tanggal_kegiatan;?>"><?php echo form_error('tanggal_kegiatan', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
                                            <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label>Nama Acara</label>
                                <div class="ui small left icon input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nama Kegiatan" name="nama_kegiatan" value="<?php echo $nama_kegiatan;?>"><?php echo form_error('nama_kegiatan', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
                                    <i class="text file outline icon"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <label>Isi Kegiatan</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Text" name="content">
                                 <?php echo $content;?>
                            </textarea><?php echo form_error('content', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
                        </div>

                        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">

                    <input class="ui small blue submit button" type="submit" value="Save">
                    </form>
```

Do I need to create two separate forms to accomplish this (one for the image upload and one for the text input)? Or is it possible to write a function in the controller that can validate and process both the upload and text input simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
    function tambah_kegiatan()
{
    //set validation properties
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kegiatan', 'Judul Berita', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) 
    {
       $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $config['max_width']  = '10240';
        $config['max_height']  = '7680';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))       //you forgot this
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($this->upload->data());
            $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
            $nm_file = time().$datafoto['orig_name'];
           $data = array(
                'nama_kegiatan' => $this->input->post('nama_kegiatan'),
                'image' => $nm_file
        );

        $this->mkegiatan->insert_kegiatan($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil ditambah'));
        redirect(site_url('admin/kegiatan'));
        }


    }

    $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/kegiatan/tambah_kegiatan', '', true);
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
}
```

and your image folder having all permissions

```
 function edit_kegiatan($id_kegiatan='')
        {



            //set validation properties

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal_kegiatan', 'Tanggal', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kegiatan', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');


            //run validation
            // jika dia ingin update data atau form validation error
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $data  = $this->mkegiatan->get_by_id($id_kegiatan);
                $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
                $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000';
                $config['max_width']  = '10240';
                $config['max_height']  = '7680';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))       //you forgot this
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    //print_r($this->upload->data());
                    $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
                    $nm_file = time().$datafoto['orig_name'];
                   $data = array(
                        'tanggal_kegiatan' => $this->input->post('tanggal_kegiatan'),
                        'nama_kegiatan' => $this->input->post('nama_kegiatan'),
                        'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
                        'image' => $nm_file
                );
                $this->mkegiatan->update_kegiatan($id_kegiatan,$data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil diupdate'));
                redirect(site_url('admin/kegiatan'));
                }
            }

            $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));



            //var_dump($data);
            //$tmp_data = array('id_kegiatan' => $id_kegiatan);

            $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/kegiatan/edit_kegiatan', $this->data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
    }
```

Comment: can you help me one more again? you can see in below i already edit and i put controller edit_kegiatan. i try edit but error Undefined variable: nama_kegiatan. how about that?

Comment: can you give me code of  your view which is for edit?

Comment: what is current_url()

Comment: i think you not passing $id_kegiatan in url

Comment: take a look,your $id value should not be empty..:)

Comment: what is var_dump($data); give result

Comment: object(stdClass)#20 (6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["id_admin"]=> string(0) "" ["nama_kegiatan"]=> string(11) "Sparing MTC" ["tanggal_kegiatan"]=> string(10) "2014-04-09" ["content"]=> string(165) "
In lesson nine of our CodeIgniter series, we'll build a small image gallery that allows you to upload files, and automatically create thumbnails.

" ["image"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: do last thing print_r($data) pls pls pls

Comment: try this $orang->nama_kegiatan

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand. more detail please?

Comment: i think your passing that $data['orang'] to view so this is object to access the nama_kegiantan you have to do  $orang->nama_kegiatan this

Comment: i try in view like this value="<?php echo $data['nama_kegiatan'];?>" but is not working